# Save web page content (php)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a site which has a page that shows the user a set of workout sessions in each table. The exercises in the sessions are href links and cannot be sent to the database as variables.

The links are displayed in tables on the page which is another reason why I cannot send them to the database.

How can I save the state of the web page, (possibly to a file) so that the user can view it later (in the existing workout section)?

Comment: Could someone with edit privileges correct the title please?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is simply create a copy of the generated site, the output control functions as mentioned would help.

However, it seems like the real issue is a little way away from what you're asking. What information do you have that you can't store in the database? Why can't you store it? You can always store data there and then regenerate the page. I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.

Can you give an example of how the data is structured in the database currently?

Comment: Ok, currently there is no table in the database to recieve this data. I assume that I can't send this data because of its structure. The data is the result of an array list and it is displayed on the page in a table.

If the data was in a form I would be ok to send it to the database. But the fact that the data is displayed in a table makes me think that I will have to save the contents of the page as a file just to save the information.

Comment: How is the data getting into the table in the first place?

Comment: Ok, the table that I have on the web page has the elements of the array list echoed into it. Thats' how the data shows up on the page.

Comment: So if you've got an array list server side, why not store that information in a database? It's the most logical solution :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are saying. How would I save the array elements that are shown on the page to the database?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the ["Output Control Functions"](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) of php?
They will buffer the output and then you can save it to a file :)